# Java Clip (Sound / Audio) Memory Leak after closing with close()

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, clip

The following code creates a new audio clip, plays it, sleeps for 3 seconds and then closes it when it is finished playing. Despite the call to close(), I am watching the memory usage of the jvm go up by the size of the sound clip every time the while loop is run.

I'm participating in a game coded in java, and am handling the sound. I cannot have the memory i'm using increase everytime a sound is played.

What am I missing?

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class ClipLeak{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    while(true){
        File soundFile = new File("./sound.wav");
        AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);

        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, sound.getFormat());
        Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        clip.open(sound);
                    sound.close();

        clip.addLineListener(new LineListener(){
            public void update(LineEvent event){
                if(event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP){
                    event.getLine().close();
                }
            }
        });

        clip.start();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this
    import java.io.File;
    import javax.sound.sampled.*;

    public class ClipLeak{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        while(true){
            File soundFile = new File("./sound.wav");
            AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);

            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, sound.getFormat());
            Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            clip.open(sound);


            clip.addLineListener(new LineListener(){
                public void update(LineEvent event){
                    if(event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP){
                        event.getLine().close();
                    }
                }
            });

            clip.start();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            if (clip.isOpen()) {
             clip.close();
             sound.close();
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure there is a memory leak and not a garbage collect delay, you could start with closing and cleaning up all resources you allocate, removing the listener and setting all references to `null`. (Move the `File` object out of the loop too.)

If that doesn't help and the javadocs don't hint at what can be cleared you can trigger a heapdump to see what objects use the memory and what their path to root is.

Comment: I let the loop run for about a minute and watched the memory climb and climb. If it was being garbage collected, I should see memory reduced along that minute right?

Comment: Not necessarily. The JVM only runs the GC when it feels like it.

Comment: That depends on how busy the rest of the code is, it might increase for a while before coming back down. The garbage collect cycle tends to display a jigsaw pattern. That's normal. Having said that you might want to close and clear the resources you use.

Comment: "Not necessarily. The JVM only runs the GC when it feels like it." no, you can cause a gc with  System.gc();